# Lightning Component not good in Commununity

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

Custom Lightning Component work ok in Lightning experience standard UI.
When I add it to a community page layout, it shrinks and gives 'internal error'.
Contacted Salesforce weeks ago but still no reply.

```
<aura:component description="ContactSearch" controller="ContactSearchCtrl" implements=" forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="contactList" type="Object[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="contactName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="birthdate" type="String" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.birthdate}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:card class="white">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-7">
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_2-of-7">
            <lightning:helptext content="Start typing to Filter Contacts by Last Name" />
            <ui:inputText placeholder="Search Name" value="{!v.contactName}" label="Surname" aura:id="contact" keyup="{!c.doInit}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-7">
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_2-of-7">
            <lightning:helptext content="Start typing to Filter Contacts by Birth Date" />
            <ui:inputDate aura:id="date" label="Birth Date" value="{!v.birthdate}" displayDatePicker="true" keyup="{!c.doInit}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-7">
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
<table >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="cont">
        <tr>
            <td>
                    {!cont.Name}
            </td>
            <!--<td>
                    {!cont.FirstName}
            </td>
            <td>
                    {!cont.LastName}
            </td>-->

            <td>
                    {!cont.Birthdate}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</table>
```

js controller

```
({
  doInit: function (component, event, helper)
  {
    helper.loadContacts(component);
  }
})
```

js helper

```
({
 loadContacts : function(component, event, helper) {
    var name = component.get("v.contactName");
    var date = component.get("v.birthdate");
    var action = component.get("c.searchForContacts");
    action.setParams({searchText : name, searchDate : date});
    console.log(action);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.contactList", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        /*var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Success!",
                "message": " Your contacts have been loaded successfully."
            });
        }
        else {
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Error!",
                "message": " Something has gone wrong."
            });
        }
        toastEvent.fire();*/
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
 },

})
```

This is before drop the component to the layout page:
[image]

This is after dropping it, it shrinks in one line and show nothing.

[image]

```
public with sharing class ContactSearchCtrl {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String searchText, String searchDate) {
    Date newDate;
    system.debug(searchDate);
    system.debug(searchText);
    /*String newSearchDate = searchDate.format();*/
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
    String query1 = 'SELECT Account.Name, Name, firstName, lastName, Age__c, Gender__c, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE \'%'+ searchText + '%\' AND RecordType.DeveloperName = \'Consult_Patient\' ORDER by lastName ASC LIMIT 10 ';
    String query2 = 'SELECT Account.Name, Name, firstName, lastName, Age__c, Gender__c, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Birthdate = '+newDate+' AND RecordType.DeveloperName = \'Consult_Patient\' ORDER by BirthDate ASC LIMIT 10 ';
    String query3 = 'SELECT Account.Name, Name, firstName, lastName, Age__c, Gender__c, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE \'%'+ searchText + '%\' AND Birthdate = '+newDate+' AND RecordType.DeveloperName = \'Consult_Patient\' ORDER by lastName ASC LIMIT 10 ';
    contactList = [SELECT Account.Name, Name, firstName, lastName, Age__c, Gender__c, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Consult_Patient' LIMIT 10];
    if(searchText!=NULL && searchDate == NULL){
        return contactList = Database.query(query1);
    }else if(searchText==NULL && searchDate!=NULL){
        newDate = Date.valueOf(searchDate);
        return contactList = Database.query(query2);
    }else if(searchText!=NULL && searchDate!=NULL){
        newDate = Date.valueOf(searchDate);
        return contactList = Database.query(query3);
    }else{
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please provide the complete error message

Comment: Updated with a screenshot, I don't know how much this can help.

Comment: Try narrowing down your code to a minimum and reach to a point where your component gets displayed - after that add code step by step, then you will find your problem

Comment: One source of "An internal server error has occurred" in Lightning is a problem with your Apex. So, try loading your community page with the developer console open and look at the Apex logs from when your controller runs. Or, wrap all of your apex in try {...} catch(Exception e) { throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage()); } then output the details in your Lightning JS somewhere. Hopefully, this will give you more info to work with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed
`<lightning:card>` tag
and now is working in community as well.

Comment: Are you saying that `lightning:card` is not supported in communities?